# Django: Filter empty model entry in Admin template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have nullable/optional fields in my model. I represent them as MultipleChoiceFields in my custom admin templates.

[image]

I wanted to filter it that if the fields are empty/null like in the photo above, it will not display anything.

here's my code:
[image]

It doesn't seem to work and still display the fields.

Is there some way to filter this?

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to print the count of these models by using "count" keyword.

After getting count information, you can add count check condition to your "if check"

for example:

```
{% if data.occupation and data.occupation.count > 1 ... %}
<p>bla bla</p>
{% else%}
<p>bla bla</p>
{%endif%}
```